# mongodb 4.0.3 property 'insertMany' of collection is not a function

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongodb and just working through the basic examples, can't get insertMany to work though. Apparently it was introduced in v3.2, but has it now been removed in 4.0.3 ?

```
> db.version()
4.0.3
> db.fruit.insertMany( [ { name: "Banana" }, { name: "Cherry" } ] );
Tue Oct 30 05:42:17.143 TypeError: Property 'insertMany' of object demo.fruit is not a function
```

In the embedded test shell on the documentation page (running v3.6) the same statement works fine:

[image]

The docs do not mention anything about deprecation of this function:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/#db.collection.insertMany

Comment: I can't reproduce, it's working fine on my system using `mongodb-linux-x86_64-4.0.3` for both the server and the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using a version of the shell prior to 3.2
I had been thinking that the query statements were evaluated on the server, but apparently not.